# why does area tag not work in my vs code editor while it's working on in w3schools lectures?

Tags: html

I am working on an `html` calendar, and i am confused about how this is not working, I have searched online, but i don't know how to fix the issue.

now i have this:

[image: THIS IMAGE]

I am using this code:

```
<img src="calendar2022.jpeg" usemap="calendar" style="border: 1px solid black;">
<map name="calendar" id="calendar">
       <area shape="rect" title="Square" coords="0,0,650,350" href="square.html" target="_blank"/>
 </map>
```

could you kindly explain the issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the '#' in your `usemap="#calendar"`.
See working example at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp)

Comment: Thanks dear. It works fine now. I am really so . . . . .